# EntityFrameworkCore with MySql not creating all tables

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to .NetCore and I am following official .NetCore Web Applicaiton tutorial, which can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

I am trying to connect my application to MySQL database using this package,  `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`

My database relationship structure is as follows:
Course, Student and Enrollment. Both course and student can have many enrollments while Enrollment record can have one Course and one Student.

```
Course -> Enrollment <- Student
```

Course.cs

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Student.cs

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Enrollment.cs

```
public class Enrollment

{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I configured dbcontext inside ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySQL(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Here is how my connection string looks like;

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;password=***;database=coremvc"
  },
```

Here is my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
 
}
```

***Notes***

**Whenever I run the project, I can only see Student and Course table automatically created but not enrollment table.**

**It worked when I removed navigation properties such as ICollection Property and Course and Student Properties. All there tables were created.**

**Presumably it has something to do with defining relationships in models.**

Thanks in advance,
Cheers

Comment: Check the following articles: [Configure Many-to-Many Relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx) and [Configuring Many To Many Relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration), in the OnModelCreating method, try to use the Fluent API to configure the join table.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html

See especially step 2.b the method OnModelCreating

The tutorial you are following is for MSSQL and you are using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MySQL, you should work with fluent API. Search for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.